Diffeomorphism between half plane and plane
Let $H$ be the half plane of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_n\geq 0$.
My aim is to prove that there are no $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $H$.

EDIT: full proof here. Search for the label  PROPooPUREooSkeyxs (in the section about manifolds with boundary)

Since I do not want to enter details about how to define the differential structure on $H$ (a $C^k$ function is a function whose accepts a $C^k$ extension on an open part of $\mathbb{R}^n$), I try to prove the following result.
There exists no maps $\psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

$\psi$ is injective
$\psi$ takes its values in $H$
$\psi$ is bijective with $H$
$\psi$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$

QUESTION : Is it true ? How to prove ?

This question is closely related to this one in which I cannot prove the his $L$ is invertible.
I bet that the result as stated here is wrong because I need the differentiability of $\psi^{-1}$. And I cannot escape to properly define the differential structure on $H$.


The differential of a diffeomorphism is invertible; it's inverse is given by the differential of the inverse map (you technically don't need to go into the definition of what it means for a function defined on a non-open set to be differentiable to make use of this). Is this enough to answer your question with the answer to the question you linked?

@BenSteffan Not exactly. Since I only know the definition of $df$ when $f$ is a map between (open parts of) normed vector spaces, I cannot even define $df$ in my context. But it turns out that working with the $dg$ where $g$ is any extension (in that case $df$ is invertible as you said), the result comes.
